# Apache CXF : definition of list elements

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I am using apache cxf 3.0.3 and we have a wsdl defined by us with following definitions:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Outer">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="myList" type="tns:MyList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MyList">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="subName" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I am using this wsdl to generate a request using soapui. In the generated request I am using the following snippet to define the Outer element:

```
<myList>
   <subName>10030</subName>
   <subName>10050</subName>
   <subName>10080</subName>
</myList>
```

but it does not work. Only the first element is deserialized in the cxf generated bean.

How do I have to change the wsdl in order to accept such input ?

Comment: Does the bean have a `Collection` or a single `String` for `subName`?

Comment: subName is a list of strings

Comment: Is what you showed us the actual request in SOAP UI?  Is there a namespace definition

Comment: The real request is very long I showed you only the list element. The current namespace is targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/mywsdl"

Comment: Can you see the value `10030` in the bean?

Comment: No, only the last one ("10080").

Comment: I think there might be a namespace issue.